# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dms.model.Group.groupId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I searched many answers for this problem, but nothing worked out for me. This is a spring mvc maven project. Please help.

Here is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", catalog = "srvcs")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer userId;
private Group group;
private String name;
private String address;
private String email;
private String tel;
private String username;
private String role;
private String status;
private Date createdDate;
private Set<Object> objectsForUpdatedBy = new HashSet<Object>(0);
private Set<Folder> foldersForCreatedBy = new HashSet<Folder>(0);
private Set<Object> objectsForCreatedBy = new HashSet<Object>(0);
private Set<Folder> foldersForOwnerId = new HashSet<Folder>(0);
private Set<Object> objectsForOwnerId = new HashSet<Object>(0);
private Set<Log> logs = new HashSet<Log>(0);
private Set<Folder> foldersForUpdatedBy = new HashSet<Folder>(0);

public User() {
}

public User(String name, String email, String tel, String username, String role, String status, Date createdDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
    this.status = status;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public User(Group group, String name, String address, String email, String tel, String username, String role,
        String status, Date createdDate, Set<Object> objectsForUpdatedBy, Set<Folder> foldersForCreatedBy,
        Set<Object> objectsForCreatedBy, Set<Folder> foldersForOwnerId, Set<Object> objectsForOwnerId,
        Set<Log> logs, Set<Folder> foldersForUpdatedBy) {
    this.group = group;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
    this.status = status;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.objectsForUpdatedBy = objectsForUpdatedBy;
    this.foldersForCreatedBy = foldersForCreatedBy;
    this.objectsForCreatedBy = objectsForCreatedBy;
    this.foldersForOwnerId = foldersForOwnerId;
    this.objectsForOwnerId = objectsForOwnerId;
    this.logs = logs;
    this.foldersForUpdatedBy = foldersForUpdatedBy;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
public Group getGroup() {
    return this.group;
}

public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "address", length = 500)
public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name = "tel", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getTel() {
    return this.tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByUpdatedBy")
public Set<Object> getObjectsForUpdatedBy() {
    return this.objectsForUpdatedBy;
}

public void setObjectsForUpdatedBy(Set<Object> objectsForUpdatedBy) {
    this.objectsForUpdatedBy = objectsForUpdatedBy;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByCreatedBy")
public Set<Folder> getFoldersForCreatedBy() {
    return this.foldersForCreatedBy;
}

public void setFoldersForCreatedBy(Set<Folder> foldersForCreatedBy) {
    this.foldersForCreatedBy = foldersForCreatedBy;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByCreatedBy")
public Set<Object> getObjectsForCreatedBy() {
    return this.objectsForCreatedBy;
}

public void setObjectsForCreatedBy(Set<Object> objectsForCreatedBy) {
    this.objectsForCreatedBy = objectsForCreatedBy;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByOwnerId")
public Set<Folder> getFoldersForOwnerId() {
    return this.foldersForOwnerId;
}

public void setFoldersForOwnerId(Set<Folder> foldersForOwnerId) {
    this.foldersForOwnerId = foldersForOwnerId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByOwnerId")
public Set<Object> getObjectsForOwnerId() {
    return this.objectsForOwnerId;
}

public void setObjectsForOwnerId(Set<Object> objectsForOwnerId) {
    this.objectsForOwnerId = objectsForOwnerId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<Log> getLogs() {
    return this.logs;
}

public void setLogs(Set<Log> logs) {
    this.logs = logs;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userByUpdatedBy")
public Set<Folder> getFoldersForUpdatedBy() {
    return this.foldersForUpdatedBy;
}

public void setFoldersForUpdatedBy(Set<Folder> foldersForUpdatedBy) {
    this.foldersForUpdatedBy = foldersForUpdatedBy;
}

}
```

And My Group class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP", catalog = "srvcs")
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer groupId;
private String groupName;
private String status;
private Date createdDate;
private int createdBy;
private Set<Folder> folders = new HashSet<Folder>(0);
private Set<Object> objects = new HashSet<Object>(0);
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

public Group() {
}

public Group(String groupName, String status, Date createdDate, int createdBy) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.status = status;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public Group(String groupName, String status, Date createdDate, int createdBy, Set<Folder> folders,
        Set<Object> objects, Set<User> users) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.status = status;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.folders = folders;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.users = users;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "group_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getGroupId() {
    return this.groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}

@Column(name = "group_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getGroupName() {
    return this.groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
public int getCreatedBy() {
    return this.createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(int createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
public Set<Folder> getFolders() {
    return this.folders;
}

public void setFolders(Set<Folder> folders) {
    this.folders = folders;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
public Set<Object> getObjects() {
    return this.objects;
}

public void setObjects(Set<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

}
```

Both the above entity classes are automatically generated using eclipse IDE. The DLL is shown below:

User Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `USER` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_group_idx` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `GROUP` (`group_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Group Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `GROUP` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `group_id_UNIQUE` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I'm getting the error inside this DAO method:

```
@Override
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public List<User> getUsersOfGroup(Integer groupId) {
    String hql = "from User usr  where usr.group = :group";
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TypedQuery<User>  query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("group", groupId);
    List<User> userList = query.getResultList();        
    if(userList != null && !userList.isEmpty()){

        return userList;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The complete error log:

```
 16:27:57,423 ERROR [org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl] (default task-2) HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.dms.model.Group, getter method of property: groupId
16:27:57,430  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dms.model.Group.groupId
16:27:57,434    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
16:27:57,434    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
16:27:57,434    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
16:27:57,435    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
16:27:57,435    at com.dms.dao.AdminDaoImpl.getUsersOfGroup(AdminDaoImpl.java:43)
16:27:57,435    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:27:57,436    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
16:27:57,438    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:27:57,438    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
16:27:57,439    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
16:27:57,439    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
16:27:57,439    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
16:27:57,440    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
16:27:57,440    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
16:27:57,441    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
16:27:57,441    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
16:27:57,441    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getUsersOfGroup(Unknown Source)
16:27:57,441    at com.dms.service.AdminServiceImpl.lambda$1(AdminServiceImpl.java:284)
16:27:57,442    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
16:27:57,442    at com.dms.service.AdminServiceImpl.getJsonStringForGroupList(AdminServiceImpl.java:276)
16:27:57,442    at com.dms.view.AdminViewImpl.getGroupListView(AdminViewImpl.java:55)
16:27:57,442    at com.dms.controller.AdminController.listGroupsValidDMSValidToken(AdminController.java:144)
16:27:57,442    at com.dms.controller.AdminController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c30026d.invoke(<generated>)
16:27:57,443    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
16:27:57,443    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
16:27:57,443    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
16:27:57,443    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
16:27:57,455    at com.dms.aspect.DMSValidation.validateToken(DMSValidation.java:130)
16:27:57,455    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:27:57,455    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
16:27:57,455    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:27:57,455    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
16:27:57,456    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:643)
16:27:57,456    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:632)
16:27:57,456    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
16:27:57,456    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
16:27:57,456    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
16:27:57,457    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
16:27:57,457    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
16:27:57,457    at com.dms.controller.AdminController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37b10a5.listGroupsValidDMSValidToken(<generated>)
16:27:57,458    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:27:57,458    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
16:27:57,458    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:27:57,458    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
16:27:57,458    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
16:27:57,458    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
16:27:57,459    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
16:27:57,459    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
16:27:57,459    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
16:27:57,459    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
16:27:57,459    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
16:27:57,460    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
16:27:57,460    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
16:27:57,460    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
16:27:57,460    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
16:27:57,460    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
16:27:57,460    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
16:27:57,460    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
16:27:57,461    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
16:27:57,461    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
16:27:57,462    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,463    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
16:27:57,463    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
16:27:57,464    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
16:27:57,464    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
16:27:57,464    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
16:27:57,464    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
16:27:57,464    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
16:27:57,464    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16:27:57,465  Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dms.model.Group.groupId
16:27:57,465    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:65)
16:27:57,465    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
16:27:57,465    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4896)
16:27:57,465    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4596)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:495)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:288)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:645)
16:27:57,466    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2000)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
16:27:57,467    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:221)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
16:27:57,468    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
16:27:57,469    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
16:27:57,469    ... 81 more
16:27:57,469  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
16:27:57,470    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:27:57,470    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
16:27:57,470    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:27:57,470    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
16:27:57,470    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
16:27:57,470    ... 105 more
```

I'm using Java8/Spring5/Hibernate5

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
from User usr  where usr.group.groupId = :group
```

Because you're passing `groupId` instead of a `Group` object

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! It worked for me. But just another doubt - The script 'from User usr  where usr.group = :group' and passing groupId has always worked  when I was using hibernate4. Is this way of scripting new in hibernate5?